# How can I use a loop in the front end to store each checkbox ticked in the loop in to an array of players

Tags: php, laravel

In the front end I have a list of players which I want to select by a checkbox to form groups. But how do I store each player ticked in the checkbox into an array?

This is my blade

```
@foreach ($players as $index=>$player)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ $player->gender }}</td>
        <td>{{ $player->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $player->handicap }}</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="Player" value="{{$player->id}}"><br>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach

{{ $players->links() }}
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: this will make an array `name="Player[]"`

Answer (score 0):

Your input field should be named `Player[]`, with the square brackets. That indicates there are multiple values for that field, so each player will have "his own" checkbox.

When you submit a form that contains array like field to your controller, you can firstly validate it with:
`"Player" => ["required", "array"]` and you can also validate each value of the array with `"Player.*" => ["required", "integer"]`. These are sample validations, but you can do a lot more (or less).

Now, to access the values, just use `$request->input('player')` just like you would with any other input, except now you will get an array, which you can loop through and implement your own logic.

### Tick checkbox based on condition

If you want to tick the checkbox based on certain condition, in your blade, you can add

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Player" value="{{$player->id}}" {{ $player->name == 'Mark' ? 'checked' : '' }} />
```